# Scroll content and slow background scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll

im looking for an scrolling page effect, I found it here: http://alterego.ae/

I really like that image slower scroll down effect then the content (with white background) but I didnt want to use javascript (I dont even know how!) to do that.

I want the same effect, without using javascript to do that.

How I achieve that?

**HTML**

```
    <div style="background-image: url(../img/bg1.png); position: 50% 10px>
    <div class="container">content (example: about us)</div>
</div>



    <div style="background-image: url(../img/bg1.png); position: 50% 10px>
    <div class="container">content (example: about us)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's known as `parallax scrolling` and it can't be done without JavaScript. You'll find tons of tutorials. It's really not too difficult

Comment: http://frozenrockets.nl/labs/parallax/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you really cannot achieve this type of scrolling (called parallax) without a bit of Javascript. However, other people on the internet have kindly written plug-ins, allowing you to implement parallax scrolling with more ease. You'll still need to use a small amount of JS to have this work, but far less than by writing the methods yourself.

I'd recommend: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr (I have no personal connection to this, just seen it before and like it!), it is easy to implement.

Sorry that this probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but parallax scrolling requires Javascript.

Comment: I dont mind, if it has a little bit of JS, but if its too complex, I might loose a lot of time to implement it